# How to find the middle of an element and use the left float

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know how I can find the middle of a `div` and use `float: left` to set `#ucp_arrow` at that position.

Screen:

[image]

---

At the moment I "hard coded" it with:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$("#a_account").click(function() { //Account
  if (ucphideshow == 1) {
    $("#userAdministration_div").show();
    $("#userCharacter_div").hide();
    $("#ucp_arrow").css("left", "46px");
  }
});
$("#a_char").click(function() { //character
  if (ucphideshow == 1) {
    $("#userAdministration_div").hide();
    $("#userCharacter_div").show();
    $("#ucp_arrow").css("left", "125px");
  }
});
```

It's working but I want to dynamically calculate the middle of the menu item.

HTML:

```
<ul class="ucp_tab" id="ucp_tab">
    <li><a href="#ucp_account" id="a_account">Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ucp_char" id="a_char"><?php echo GetLang("Charakter","Character"); ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.ucp_box_arrow_up {
display: block;
width: 14px;
height: 8px;
background-image: url('../images/icons/icons.png');
background-position: -39px -143px;
position: absolute;
left: 46px;
z-index: 2;
top: 104px;
-webkit-transition: left 500ms;
-moz-transition: left 500ms;
-o-transition: left 500ms;
transition: left 500ms;
}
```

Comment: The middle of a `div` is half of its width.

Comment: Yeah i know but i dont know how can i use it with float: left, i want the exactly middle of the div. i move the arrow with left

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: You can make it a pseudo element with absolute positioning...No float.

Comment: /* Edit: Insert the div at the top of the thread

Comment: You should be making that triangle/arrow/chevron using before and after pseudo elements like @AlexRindone mentioned.

Comment: Is there no way to make it with jquery? because i use a left transition. Also i want to knew how can i make that with jquery

Comment: Don't use jquery if you don't need to. In your case you can do it pure CSS. On hover, you would create a pseudo element that is absolutely positioned.

Comment: Yeah i know but i want to use a left transition and with pseudo element is it not possible to make that. but also i want to know how can i do it with jquery

Comment: Nobody have a good idee?

Answer (score 0):

Just get the width of the button minus the width of the arrow and divide by 2

```
$("#a_account").click(function() {
    ...
    $("#ucp_arrow").css("left", ($(this).outerWidth()-$("#ucp_arrow").outerWidth())/2);
    ...
});
```

I'm assuming (better post you CSS to stop assuming) that you're using `position: absolute` on `#ucp_arrow`. If you change the absolute positioning for `float: left`, set the `margin-left` instead of `left`.

Comment: Thank you for you anwser. But it not working. On the first "a_account" its worked but by clicking "a_char" is set the position instead maybe 1px left to the old arrow.